# Getting the coordinates of a point of a picture loaded with imager in R

Tags: r, image, coordinates

Let's open an image with `imager`.

```
library(imager)


file <- system.file('extdata/parrots.png',package='imager')
#system.file gives the full path for a file that ships with a R package
#if you already have the full path to the file you want to load just run:
#im <- load.image("/somedirectory/myfile.png")
im <- load.image(file)

plot(im) #Parrots!
```

[image]

I would like to get the coordinates of two points in this picture: the eyes, as shown here:

[image]

How can I get the numerical values of the XY coordinates of both points?

Answer (score 2):

I found a very simple solution: running `locator()` you can click on wherever in the plot and after Scaping, we get the XY coordinates in the R shell.